# git push heroku master getting following error

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I'm attempting to deploy my code to heroku with the following command line:

```
 $ git push heroku master
    Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Did you set up ssh keys? Does it work for other apps? Check out: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Comment: yes when type $ heroku keys i have see two keys

=== kambleshankar1987@gmail.com Keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...43gqIWww== dinesh@VI-L011 ,
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...Ixe5FDKw== dinesh@VI-L011

Comment: What about `heroku info`

Comment: $ heroku info
=== fast-tundra-1128
Git URL:       git@heroku.com:fast-tundra-1128.git
Owner Email:   kambleshankar1987@gmail.com
Region:        us
Stack:         cedar
Tier:          Legacy
Web URL:       http://fast-tundra-1128.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Can you try `git pull`

Comment: Are you using heroku-accounts plugin? Here is more info: http://rakshasingh.weebly.com/1/post/2013/04/accessing-multiple-heroku-accounts-from-one-machine.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your key.

```
 heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

see this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys